# How encoded filename in S3 Presigned url in ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

in S3 presigned url how I can encoded the string $filename

```
s3.bucket(ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME')).presigned_post(
  key: "uploads/#{Time.now.to_i}/${filename}",
  allow_any: ['authenticity_token'],
  acl:'public-read',
  metadata: {
    'original-filename' => '${filename}'
  },
  success_action_status: "201"
)
```

sometime the filename include some special char or spaces. I would like to avoid them in the key

Answer (score 2):

To cast your filename to url-safe form you may use 2 options:

- If you are using Rails you may try to use `.parameterize` method. See
  https://apidock.com/rails/String/parameterize
- If you are using plain Ruby:

  > filename.gsub(%r{\s}, '_').gsub(%r{[^a-zA-Z0-9-.]+}, '')

  Sample:

  > 'asf asfa 1-240((($@))!@.jpeg'.gsub(%r{\s}, '_').gsub(%r{[^a-zA-Z0-9-.]+}, '')
  >   => "asfasfa1-240.jpeg"

  Both approaches should throw away any spaces and special characters.